# How do you compute $1+x+\cdots+x^7=0 \mod 40$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I think the first step is to us the fact that $(x-1)(x^7+\cdots+x+1)=x^8-1$.

This makes the problem into find $x^8=1 \mod 40$, which is where I am stuck. I know that $x$ can't be even or one, but I do not know a process that will find the actual values without brute force computations. I'm not sure how to know it is solvable, but because of Wolfram I know it is. I know $\phi(40)=16$, but not sure where that helps. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: A first step would be to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to break it down to $x^8\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and $x^8\equiv 1 \pmod5$.

Comment: I like this approach, I solved each of these congruence equations and got x=1,3,5,7 for the first one and x=1,2,3,4 for the second. I know I should ignore the x=1 solutions, but how do I get the solutions from these?

Comment: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem algorithm, I should have spotted that earlier. That solves the problem! and using a method I have discussed from class, thanks for getting me on track Henning

Comment: @actually, you shouldn't ignore _both_ the $x=1$ solutions because $x=1$ is still a solution to $1+x+\cdots+x^7\equiv 0\pmod 8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lambda(40)=4 \Rightarrow x^8 \equiv 1 \pmod{40}$ iff $\gcd(x,40)=1$

Comment: What is the lambda function? I haven't come across that yet. Is there another way to do this without using it?

Comment: So I looked it up and this makes perfect sense and would be an easy question, but since we haven't discussed this function in class yet I'll have to find another way to do the problem. Thanks though!